# XAML WinRT Chart Remove Axis Label

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

Im Using the Chart library "ModernUI Toolkit" (http://modernuitoolkit.codeplex.com/).
How can I remove the Label in WinRT?

I found some answers but it was for the Silverlight version and this does not work with this library.

Here is my XAML Code:

```
<Chart:Chart x:Name="LineChart" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Title="Line Chart" Margin="24,222,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="318" Height="342">
    <Series:StackedLineSeries x:Name="StackedLineSeries">
    </Series:StackedLineSeries>
</Chart:Chart>
```

Comment: Note that WinRT XAML Toolkit has a slightly newer version of the chart code from ModernUI Toolkit - essentially a merge of that with another port of the chart control from Silverlight Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be something like this:

```
<Series:StackedLineSeries.IndependentAxis>
    <Series:LinearAxis
        xmlns:datavis="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization">
        <Series:LinearAxis.TitleStyle>
            <Style
                TargetType="datavis:Title">
                <Setter
                    Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Style>
        </Series:LinearAxis.TitleStyle>
    </Series:LinearAxis>
</Series:LineSeries.IndependentAxis>
```

Comment: Namespaces would be different of course when using ModernUI Toolkit.